# Investing max tax-deferred IRA contribution Dec 2022 vs Jan 2023 for contribution year 2022

Tags: united-states, etf, ira

If contributing for tax year 2022 into a tax-advantaged IRA ETF, is there any benefit waiting until Jan 2023 vs Dec 2022? I am remembering something that happens at end of year with ETFs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If contributing for tax year 2022 into a tax-advantaged IRA ETF, is
> there any benefit waiting until Jan 2023 vs Dec 2022? I am remembering
> something that happens at end of year with ETFs?

If you are investing in a fund in a taxable account in December then you run the risk that just days after making the investment the fund will pay a dividend or capital gains distribution. In a taxable account that will mean that the dividend/capital gain will be included on your tax forms you submit in April the next year. You may have to pay taxes on that distribution.

If in a taxable account you wait until they have made the end of year distributions, then you won't have that quick taxable distribution. Note when a fund makes a distribution the value of a share of the fund also drops.

In a retirement account the distribution from the fund, doesn't trigger taxes the following April. In a traditional retirement account the income will be taxed in a later year, in a Roth account the distribution will not have any tax consequences.
Therefore there is no reason to wait until January just to avoid a distribution.

Note: the decision to reinvest the distributions doesn't impact the tax situation.

Comment: The _cost_ of the shares may also drop by the amount of the (expected) dividend, since everyone else is factoring this in too. ... I tend to agree that this all balances out and makes little difference to final results.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any benefit waiting until Jan 2023 vs Dec 2022?

No, unless you're trying to time the market (in which case, you might as well buy a lottery ticket too). Nothing happens to ETFs at the end of a year as a matter of general policy.